# Remove curvature from 360 images, without editing all files by hand?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, blender

I created .gif file with 360 frames from a rotating tower in blender, every frame is 1 degree of rotation. However, there is a bit of curvature on the left and right end of frames. I want to make them all completely rectangular, but I don't feel like editing all 360 frames.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/tWhiH]

What would be the best way to modify all the frames at the same time, because the curving on the edges is the same for every frame?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Except for the middle ones, all shapes are trapezoids, not rectangles. Any kind of curvature is hard to spot anywhere. Please specify...

Comment: @AAGD I'm not entirely sure how to explain it. However, on the left and right side, the height is less then it's in the middle. I want to change it so that it is no longer trapezoids but rectangular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to omit the perspective distortion you need to set your blender camera to ortho mode. This should create a parallel projection without the distortion.

Comment: One more thing: You probably wont need 360 frames for this. You just need the full movement of one field, then just loop it.